# Was Adam "buried" where he was "created" as Jubilees states? If so, was Adam possibly buried on Mt. Moriah?

Tags: geography, temple, adam, death, rabbinic-interpretation

**How to make sense of Jubilees 4:29, which states Adam was buried where he was created? Was he buried on Mt. Moriah (where multiple references say he was created)?**

I know tradition states that Adam was buried in the cave of Machpelah (The Tomb/Caves of the Patriarchs in present-day Hebron) as is indicated in BT Erubin 53a, BT Sotah 13a, BT Baba Batra 58a, Bereshith Rabbah 58:4-8 and later sources like the Zohar.

However, I have also read that Adam was **buried where he was "created."** And... there are several accounts stating that **Adam was created on Mount Moriah/grounds of the sanctuary/Temple.**

**Buried where he was created:**

Jubilees 4:29: "Adam died. And all of his children ***buried him in the land of his creation.*** And he was the first who was buried in the earth."

**And where was he created?**

Pseudo-Jonathan (Targumist) Genesis 1-6: "And the Lord ***God created man*** in two formations; and took ***dust from the place of the house of the sanctuary,*** and from the four winds of the world, and mixed all the waters of the world, and created him red, black, and white; and breathed into his nostrils the inspiration of life, and there was in the body of Adam the inspiration of a speaking spirit, unto the illumination of the eyes and the hearing of the ears..."

Pseudo-Jonathan (Targumist) Genesis. 3:23:  "And the Lord God removed him from the garden of Eden; and he went and dwelt ***on Mount Moriah***, to cultivate the ***ground from which he had been created***."

Pirke DeRabbi Eliezer 12: "With love abounding did the Holy One, blessed be He, love the first man, inasmuch as ***He created him*** in  a pure locality, ***in the place of the Temple***."

**So could one argue that Adam was created AND buried on the Temple Mount?** And in the grand scheme of things, Hebron is but 19 miles from Jerusalem... So could the Machpelah Cave and Mount Moriah references actually be one and the same? After all, the Machpelah cave is strongly tied to being the entrance to the Garden of Eden, and isn't the Garden of Eden a symbol of a Temple, a heaven on earth?

I know the argument that Adam was buried on the Temple Mount clashes directly and drastically with purity laws (i.e. contact with the dead makes one impure, and you need to be pure in the Temple), which makes me think this theory does not hold true.

**Have there been any established scholarly arguments that Adam was buried on Mt. Moriah (despite purity laws) in light of Jubilees account?**

Comment: Are you concerned with whether or not Adam's burial occurred as described in Jubilees or how to reconcile Adam being buried on Mt. Moriah with purity concerns regarding being near the temple? Please ask only one question and make it crystal clear what that single question is. Thanks.

Comment: Well, both. But primarily, whether or not Adam's burial occurred as described in Jubilees. And if so... then the purity questions, but that can be a question for another day. I mainly want to know if there is an established argument based on Jubilees's account that Adam theoretically was buried on Mt. Moriah.

Comment: So you are aware that there are two differing accounts (one that has him born in a cave and one on a mountain) and you are hoping to identify which is the correct account? Have you identified which is the older account yet? Other things being equal I might be inclined to be looking at the date of the sources. Jubilees appears to be 2nd century BC. What about the traditional sources? Thanks. I have reservations about accepting Jubilees as a late arrival with a completely new account unless the traditional is not any older.

Comment: No, I do not know the reference/account for the one where he was born in a cave. That would be interesting to know. Yeah, if I can establish where Jubilees thinks Adam was created that would help my understanding of the passage. :)  Thank you!

Comment: Browsing Wikipedia it appears the traditional view from the Babylonian Talmud might not be that much older. Well, a couple centuries older. So both sources seem fairly recent. You might want to read some of the relevant Talmud and see what you think. However, I don't think you'll find either source very well vetted for accuracy. In other words I think the historical record is not going to get you an account you can be sure of.

Comment: @Ruminator It is not about Adam "born in a cave", it is about Adam "buried in a cave", isn't it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question primarily concerns the book of Jubilees and other texts not necessarily related to the Bible.